# Make HTTP Request from Custom Keyboard App Extension

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios-app-extension

My custom keyboard app extension is behaving differently on my real device, but fine on my iOS simulator.

I get the following errors on my real device

```
2017-02-17 16:30:01.369868 Custom Keyboard[8472:570942] [default] error registring notify port: (1000000)
2017-02-17 16:30:01.371652 Custom Keyboard[8472:570889] [Common] BKSAccelerometer unable to create notifyd token for device orientation
2017-02-17 16:30:01.702241 Custom Keyboard[8472:570940] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash_libsystem libsystem simulate crash failed "libsystem_network.dylib: networkd_settings_setup_notify_watch :: notify_register_dispatch(com.apple.system.networkd.settings) [status 1000000] failed"
2017-02-17 16:30:01.706023 Custom Keyboard[8472:570940] [] networkd_settings_setup_notify_watch notify_register_dispatch(com.apple.system.networkd.settings) [status 1000000] failed, dumping backtrace:
```

And I'm using standard Alamofire code:

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").response { response in
    print("Request: \(response.request)")
    print("Response: \(response.response)")
    print("Error: \(response.error)")

    if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print("Data: \(utf8Text)")
    }
}
```

I really don't understand what is going on here.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You need to have full-access to make your custom keyboard network-enabled.

Go to Info.plist, look inside the NSExtensionAttributes and change RequestsOpenAccess to YES.

Then when installing the keyboard on your iOS device, move the full access switch on.

Comment: As soon as I do this and make a request from viewDidLoad() of my KeyboardViewController (subclass of UIInputViewController)....my keyboard stops switching. It never shows up again no matter what I do...I reset the simulator and tried...but no luck...can u help?

Comment: Sorry, it's been ages since I've been working on this and I cannot remember anything significant.

Comment: @iAnurag So...what's the answer?

Answer (score 5):

Go to Info.plist.

1. Look inside "NSExtension -> NSExtensionAttributes ->
   RequestsOpenAccess to YES".
2. You must add "App Transport Security Settings -> Allow
       Arbitrary Loads to YES".

Then,

1. Go to Apple Settings, and select "General".
2. Tap "Keyboard" and then "Keyboards".
3. Tap "YourKeyboard", and then toggle the "Allow Full Access" switch.
4. Press "Allow".